# Dynamic height based on another element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, dynamic

HTML:

```
<div class="main" style="float:left">
  lorem ipsum <br />
  lorem ipsum <br />
  lorem ipsum <br />
</div>
<div style="float:right">
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.block').height($(".main").height() / (3));
```

... each block height = height of main / 3

It is inaccurate because height doesn't consider the margin/padding of the .block. How do I subtract the padding/margin either automatically or manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`outerHeight`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/outerHeight#margin)

```
$('.block').height($(".main").outerHeight( true ) / 3);
```

**EDIT** I misread the docs originally, and thought `margin` was included by default. I was wrong! Be sure to pass `true` to the `outerHeight` function to include margin. *Thanks @Alex Sexton!*

Comment: If you want to include the margin, be sure to pass in `true` to the `outerHeight` function.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the outerHeight and outerWidth methods in jQuery

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/outerHeight

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/outerWidth

Hope that helps!